# Is a qubit passing through a gate a 3D rotation of the vector on the Bloch sphere?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

When a qubit passes through a gate isnt it a 3D rotation of the vector on the Bloch sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the state of the qubit is a single-qubit state, yes (i.e. it should be separable from all other qubits). If your qubit is etnangled with other qubits, the description is more complex.

(You also have to be careful what you mean by "the vector". That doesn't mean the state vector, but rather the Bloch vector.)